# Why is this being output?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to learn XSLT and having some issues. I would think that this line `<xsl:template match="response/results">` would limit the xlst process to only those elements within the `<results>` element???

There are some initial values being output by this and I can't figure out why. In the results below, you will see the following at the beginning of the results:

```
manhattan WMOS
true
false
60
1
10
0
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<response version="2">
    <query>manhattan WMOS</query>
    <location></location>
    <dupefilter>true</dupefilter>
    <highlight>false</highlight>
    <totalresults>60</totalresults>
    <start>1</start>
    <end>10</end>
    <pageNumber>0</pageNumber>
    <results>
        <result>
            <jobtitle>Manhattan Associates WMoS QA Analyst</jobtitle>
            <company>CMAC Inc</company>
            <city>Asheville</city>
            <state>NC</state>
            <country>US</country>
            <formattedLocation>Asheville, NC</formattedLocation>
            <source>JobServe USA</source>
            <date>Thu, 11 Oct 2012 15:20:31 GMT</date>
            <snippet>Manhattan Associtates WMoS Loads of Documentation and detail required for this position Immediate opening for 2 Senior QA Analysts Project: Manhattan (WMOS... </snippet>
            <url>http://www.indeed.com/viewjob?jk=06bef17e206740d3&amp;qd=Cg_V6UykGXt-ccaEWxs0BA1LyorWd-7Tcbya1NtZKa9WZ1DtngXSHw91EGjVCy_rntA_Y_5cpbSuoLd44_xEjXNG-vBD0DC792zHqZRp6lE&amp;indpubnum=1813651566614396&amp;atk=179li835k18b17ae</url>
            <onmousedown>indeed_clk(this, &#039;5585&#039;);</onmousedown>
            <jobkey>06bef17e206740d3</jobkey>
            <sponsored>false</sponsored>
            <expired>false</expired>
            <formattedLocationFull>Asheville, NC</formattedLocationFull>
            <formattedRelativeTime>5 days ago</formattedRelativeTime>
        </result>
        <result>
            <jobtitle>Software Analyst - WMOS</jobtitle>
            <company>Manhattan Associates</company>
            <city>Atlanta</city>
            <state>GA</state>
            <country>US</country>
            <formattedLocation>Atlanta, GA</formattedLocation>
            <source>Manhattan Associates</source>
            <date>Mon, 01 Oct 2012 21:02:50 GMT</date>
            <snippet>innovations include: Manhattan SCOPE® a portfolio of... Position open in Atlanta Office. About Manhattan Associates:  Manhattan Associates is at the forefront of... </snippet>
            <url>http://www.indeed.com/viewjob?jk=a17a7c578a779db8&amp;qd=Cg_V6UykGXt-ccaEWxs0BA1LyorWd-7Tcbya1NtZKa9WZ1DtngXSHw91EGjVCy_rntA_Y_5cpbSuoLd44_xEjXNG-vBD0DC792zHqZRp6lE&amp;indpubnum=1813651566614396&amp;atk=179li835k18b17ae</url>
            <onmousedown>indeed_clk(this, &#039;5585&#039;);</onmousedown>
            <jobkey>a17a7c578a779db8</jobkey>
            <sponsored>false</sponsored>
            <expired>false</expired>
            <formattedLocationFull>Atlanta, GA</formattedLocationFull>
            <formattedRelativeTime>14 days ago</formattedRelativeTime>
        </result>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:param name="ItemsToShow" select="'2'"/>
<xsl:param name="ShowItemDetails" select="'true'"/>
<xsl:param name="ShowItemDate" select="'true'"/>
<xsl:param name="Locale"/>
<xsl:param name="Target"/>
  <xsl:variable name="apos">'</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template name="google_analytics_event_tracking">
    <xsl:param name="link_category" />
    <xsl:param name="link_sub_category" />
     <xsl:param name="link_data" />

  <xsl:value-of select="concat('_gaq.push([', $apos, '_trackEvent', $apos, ',', $apos, $link_category, $apos, ',', $apos, $link_sub_category, $apos, ',', $apos, $link_data, $apos,')]')" />
</xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="response/results">
    <xsl:for-each select="result[position()&lt;=$ItemsToShow or $ItemsToShow&lt;1]">
        <xsl:variable name="jobOutboundLinkAction">
            <xsl:call-template name="google_analytics_event_tracking">
                <xsl:with-param name="link_category" select="'indeed.com'" />
                <xsl:with-param name="link_sub_category" select="'none'" />
                <xsl:with-param name="link_data" select="url" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <div class="jobWrapper">
            <div class="jobTitle">
                <a href="{url}">
                    <xsl:attribute name="target">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$Target"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$jobOutboundLinkAction"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="jobtitle"/>
                </a>
            </div>
            <xsl:if test="$ShowItemDate='true'">
                <h6>
                    <xsl:value-of select="date"/>
                </h6>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$ShowItemDetails='true'">
                Company: <xsl:value-of select="company" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                <br />
                <xsl:value-of select="formattedLocation" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                <br />
                <p>
                    <xsl:value-of select="snippet" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                </p>
            </xsl:if>
            <div class="cleaner"></div>
        </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
manhattan WMOS
true
false
60
1
10
0
<div class="jobWrapper">
    <div class="jobTitle">
        <a href="http://www.indeed.com/viewjob?jk=06bef17e206740d3&amp;qd=Cg_V6UykGXt-ccaEWxs0BA1LyorWd-7Tcbya1NtZKa9WZ1DtngXSHw91EGjVCy_rntA_Y_5cpbSuoLd44_xEjXNG-vBD0DC792zHqZRp6lE&amp;indpubnum=1813651566614396&amp;atk=179li835k18b17ae" target="" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','indeed.com','none','http://www.indeed.com/viewjob?jk=06bef17e206740d3&amp;qd=Cg_V6UykGXt-ccaEWxs0BA1LyorWd-7Tcbya1NtZKa9WZ1DtngXSHw91EGjVCy_rntA_Y_5cpbSuoLd44_xEjXNG-vBD0DC792zHqZRp6lE&amp;indpubnum=1813651566614396&amp;atk=179li835k18b17ae')]">Manhattan Associates WMoS QA Analyst</a>
    </div>
    <h6>Thu, 11 Oct 2012 15:20:31 GMT</h6>
    Company: CMAC Inc<br>
        Asheville, NC<br>
            <p>Manhattan Associtates WMoS Loads of Documentation and detail required for this position Immediate opening for 2 Senior QA Analysts Project: Manhattan (WMOS... </p>
            <div class="cleaner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="jobWrapper">
            <div class="jobTitle">
                <a href="http://www.indeed.com/viewjob?jk=a17a7c578a779db8&amp;qd=Cg_V6UykGXt-ccaEWxs0BA1LyorWd-7Tcbya1NtZKa9WZ1DtngXSHw91EGjVCy_rntA_Y_5cpbSuoLd44_xEjXNG-vBD0DC792zHqZRp6lE&amp;indpubnum=1813651566614396&amp;atk=179li835k18b17ae" target="" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','indeed.com','none','http://www.indeed.com/viewjob?jk=a17a7c578a779db8&amp;qd=Cg_V6UykGXt-ccaEWxs0BA1LyorWd-7Tcbya1NtZKa9WZ1DtngXSHw91EGjVCy_rntA_Y_5cpbSuoLd44_xEjXNG-vBD0DC792zHqZRp6lE&amp;indpubnum=1813651566614396&amp;atk=179li835k18b17ae')]">Software Analyst - WMOS</a>
            </div>
            <h6>Mon, 01 Oct 2012 21:02:50 GMT</h6>
            Company: Manhattan Associates<br>
                Atlanta, GA<br>
                    <p>innovations include: Manhattan SCOPE® a portfolio of... Position open in Atlanta Office. About Manhattan Associates:  Manhattan Associates is at the forefront of... </p>
                    <div class="cleaner"></div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). Also, I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You can run this here: http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/YWkbQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, found [this link](http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/xslapplytemplates.php)

Added this to filter out the unwanted:

```
<xsl:template match="response">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="results"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Yes, that will do the trick too, as long as the root element is always response, and your main template does not call any further xsl:apply-templates. It is unsafe though, as any further development of your template is likely to include an xsl:apply-templates instruction.

Comment: Though this works, when I process it through .NET, I get this error:   "Token StartElement in state EndRootElement would result in an invalid XML document. Make sure that the ConformanceLevel setting is set to ConformanceLevel.Fragment or ConformanceLevel.Auto if you want to write an XML fragment. System.InvalidOperationException". Is this related?

Comment: Probably your XML is malformed. If you show your current XML output, we might be able to say.

Comment: Also your use of disable-output-escaping is very dangerous. It is likely to lead to malformation errors. Reconsider if you actually need it. There is almost never a legitimate reason to use it.

Comment: Sean, thanks for all your time in responding. The output is HTML not XML, and it seems to be formed ok from what I can see. You can run it here: http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/YWkbQL. It works under the Browser(JavaScript) processor, but not .NET. In the end I am using the DotNetNuke news module to display an RSS feed. I am using this XLS to modify it. It is using XSLT 1.0 and .Net as the processor. The raw feed is coming from Indeed.com in which keywords are used to produce a result list of jobs. The keywords will be hard coded (i.e. not user selected) and there will only be a few combos.

Answer (score 0):

You have only got one matchable template. So everything that does not match that one will by processed by the XSLT in-built templates.

You need to create additional templates for other elements. Something like this...

```
<xsl:template match="*" />
```

... will sink all elements not specifically matched by your other templates.

Comment: As an XSLT newb, could you possibly give me a little more direction on this. I tried just putting what you specified as the last template, but then nothing was output. And guessing from your comment on my given answer, I suspect this solution maybe a better approach?

Comment: The best way to get XSLT help is to specify the following things: (1) XLST version and processor; (2) At least one good use case; and (3) a narrative to define any rules of transformation that are not implied by the use cases. A use case is a simple sample document, with coverage of edge cases, and a matching expected output document.